# Passing a set of structurally typed elements

Tags: scala

I have a function:

`def collapse(relations: Set[Relation] ...`

Where `Relation` is a structural type

```
  type Relation = {
    def source: NodeId
    def target: NodeId
  }
```

I have two case classes:

```
case class ViewRelation(id: Option[NodeId],
                        source: NodeId,
                        target: NodeId, ...
```

and

```
case class IndirectRelation(source: NodeId,
                        target: NodeId...
```

I can not, for practical reasons, make them extend from the same trait. Therefore I have decided to use a structural type.

I want to pass a `val viewRelations = Set[ViewRelation]` and `val indirectRelations: Set[IndirectRelation]` as an argument: `collapse(viewRelations ++ indirectRelations)`. Unfortunately that does not seem to work. Even passing just `viewRelations` or `indirectRelations` does not work. I finally worked around it this way:

`collapse(Set[Relation](relations.toSeq: _*) ++ Set[Relation](indirectRelations.toSeq: _*))`

Is there a better way? This is very wasteful as I can expect relatively large numbers of relations and the operation will need to run often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `Set.empty[Relation] ++ viewRelations ++ indirectRelations`.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. Perhaps you could enlighten me a bit on how you figured that that should work?

Comment: The inner workings of `scala.collection` are still quite obscure to me, but this is the best way I found to fill a collection while enforcing its type: create an empty one and then add everything I want. The CanBuildFrom magic do the rest.